# I am getting this error "NameError: name 'Stack' is not defined" I am not sure how to fix it

Tags: nameerror

The code adds five subsequent values onto the stack, prints their sum, and takes them all off the stack.

```
class AddingStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self):
        Stack.__init__(self)
        self.__sum=0

    def getSum(self):
        return self.__sum

    def push(self, val):
        self.__sum += val
        Stack.push(self,val)

    def pop(self):
        val=Stack.pop(self)
        self.__sum -= val
        return val

stack=AddingStack()
for i in range(5):
    stack.push(i)
print(stack.getSum())
for i in range(5):
    print(stack.pop())
```

Comment: What is your `Stack` which try to inherit in `class AddingStack(Stack)`. You may missing an import from libs.

Comment: I think it refers to the 'Stack' inside "AddingStack(Stack)" because the lesson I am in did not mention any imports. Is there a way to define the class input?

Comment: Assuming you are using python, `Stack` is not standard language class. I guess the previous lesson must have a pre-defined class name `Stack`.

Comment: You were right. I got the code working. Thank you so much!!!